# Gaps in column between paragraphs

Tags: paragraphs, elsarticle

I've just come to the end of writing a document and find that some gaps between paragraphs look as expected (see first image) and some do not (see second image):

[image]

And the second image:

[image]

I am using the `elsarticle` document class:

```
\documentclass[preprint, 12pt, 3p, twocolumn, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
```

If that makes any difference.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Using `\interlinepenalty=10000` (a suggestion I found by Googling) doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Maybe try adding the directive `\raggedbottom` to your preamble (the default is `\flushbottom`,  which would explain the blank spaces.

Comment: @Bernard You're a genius. It worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Only Ray Charles was The Genius… ;o)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments. Or Bernard provides an answer :).